# Autosys job automation

Tags: shell

We get multiple user request to hold run or kill the jobs running in our autosys server

I want to crete a script which will take input as joobname and what send event they want as input parameter and then trigger the respective job as per requirement .

Can it be done.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the answer is the `killall`command ([Examples](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/58e72888-6340-46ac-b488-d31aa4058e9c/entry/linux_killall_command_explained_with_examples7?lang=en))

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You need to create a script with the following information.

Either you can store all the job names which you want to kill via script in text file which will be parm file and then read this file in the script. A script will be having an logic to read the file which will be having job names and while running the script you can pass the ICE_TYPE ( it can be ON_ICE/OFF_ICE/KILLJOB/....or any event)

A script will be having following main code so if you say created script autosysICE.sh then you need to run the script in the following manner.

Shell > Wrapper autosysICE.sh

Following is the important line we need to embed into the script which will take argument as KILLJOB  and will replace it with the $ICE_TYPE.

sendevent -E $ICE_TYPE -J JOB_NAME

The rest you can do with the help of array read the job names from file and go through it

Code Snippet ( Note : I haven't tested this but this is the logic )

```
open(DATA,"<autosysParm.txt") or die "Can't open data";
@jobList= <DATA>;
close(DATA);

foreach my $jobName (@jobList) {
   sendevent -E $ICE_TYPE -J $jobName
}
```

Let me know if you still having an issue.
Thanks!

Comment: I got this logis but $ICE_TYPE sholud also be there in the file you mean to say along with the job name

Comment: can you please be little more elaborate.Actually scenario is there are multiple users so they cant access the file so what we have to do is we would give them location where they will put file with two parameters put the jobname and what to do(on_ice,force start or any send_event).And each user can put multiple jobs in afile adn send events also w.

Comment: To make it better we get mail from users for multiple jobs and what to do(like force_start,on_hold) etc so what we wnat is we should ask user to put ther jobs in a file along with what they want for that job and our script will read the jobname and what todo from file and go and trigger the sendevnt in autosys for all the jobs requested in afile

Comment: ok got it! so are you saying  all  this ppl are going to  use  same files  or different file?  also i would like to mention one thing here the file should not be editable during job run i mean to say you should only give users window time say 7am-10am(eg)..and after reading your details script design looks to be pretty simple.. the most of important point here is to read the file if you are thinking  of multiple files which will give you job name and event type...

Comment: Yes i want to give them multiple files whenever they want they will drop a file which will have the jobnames they want with what they want to do...our script will run whole 24*7 whenever it sees a new file in the location it will read that file and search jobnames along with what to do and then trigger the send evnt in autosys.  but as of sttarting point if above cannot be done then kindly let me know the code which we wil design to read the file with parameters as jobname and whatdo...